# How I can represent stored procedure in devexpress report chart bar

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have this stored procedure

```
USE [SIM]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE RepSumLigne
    @Date DATE
AS
    SELECT
        SUM(AssemblyWeight) AS 'Ligne Assemblage',
        SUM(WeldingWeight)  AS 'Ligne Soudage',
        SUM(PaintWeight)    AS 'Ligne Peinture' 
    FROM
        DailyProduction
    WHERE
        CreationDate = @Date
```

and I have created a report that that contain a table and chart bar, the table shows result correct, but the chart bar show nothing, for the chart bar I create three series (Ligne Assemblage, Ligne Soudage and Ligne Peinture) and in data section I set the value of each one. but when I run the report it  is show empty

[image]

I open the repeort on a click of a button

```
private void btnLigneProduSumry_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DateEdit ProducationDay = new DateEdit();
        ProducationDay.Properties.HighlightHolidays = false;
        ProducationDay.Properties.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;

        XtraInputBoxArgs args = new XtraInputBoxArgs();
        args.Caption = Resources.date;
        args.Prompt = Resources.chooseDate;
        args.DefaultButtonIndex = 0;
        args.DefaultResponse = DateTime.Today;
        args.Editor = ProducationDay;
        var result = XtraInputBox.Show(args);

        RepLigneProductionSumm report = new RepLigneProductionSumm();
        report.DataSource = paint.LigneProductionSummRep(Convert.ToDateTime(ProducationDay.EditValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        report.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
    }
```

and the code behind the LigneProductionSummRep

```
public DataTable LigneProductionSummRep(string DateProduction)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[0].Value = DateProduction;

        dt = DAL.SelectData("LigneProductionSummRep", param);
        DAL.Close();
        return dt;

    }
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance                            Update:I have put Ligne Assemblage on both Argument and Value

[image]

and tha DataSource to none
[image]

the chart bar look like this
[image]

Comment: and how do you retrieve the data ? maybe you have some code how you call the procedure and bind it to the chart ?

Comment: I have add some code to the question,please review it

Answer (score 0):

i found this soultion on youtube,i have create chart bar withoyt any datasource and int chart designer i add three bar series ,in my report i put this code

```
        private void xrChart1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        xrChart1.Series["Ligne Assemblage"].Points.Add(new DevExpress.XtraCharts.SeriesPoint("Ligne Assemblage", txtAssembly.Text));
        xrChart1.Series["Ligne Soudage"].Points.Add(new DevExpress.XtraCharts.SeriesPoint("Ligne Soudage", txtWelding.Text));
        xrChart1.Series["Ligne Peinture"].Points.Add(new DevExpress.XtraCharts.SeriesPoint("Ligne Peinture", txtPaint.Text));
    }
```